# How to get a short unique URL using mod_rewrite in the following case?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm coding for a project similar to pastebin. Each snippet should be accessible by some short unique URL that everyone can access. For example, if I make a new snippet, then that would have a associated URL like /2k3nan5. Anyone who visits yourwebsite.com/2k3nan5 should see that snippet.

I create a random string for each snippet that is being pasted e.g., 2k3nan5. I store the code of the snippet(*code*), username of the user who posted it (*username*) and the random string(*url*) in the *snippet* table of the database.

How do I alter .htaccess for doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? There are many examples of this if you simply search for htaccess and mod_rewrite.

Comment: You use a database, for each _new_ such URL you generate the "short code", a simple counter will do, and store the final location (URL) in an entry in the database. Then, at request time, you take the provided short code in the request and can query the final target URL from the database.

Comment: I tried a lot and found the answer and it is working. I'll update it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})/?$ deltatask/snippet.php?url=$1 [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

This helped me in rewriting www.website.com/abcdefg to www.website.com/deltatask/snippet.php?url=abcdefg

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite code remove file name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snippet.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snippet.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snippet.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you suggest me a good site to learn about mod_rewrite so that I can understand the code you gave as an answer?

Comment: @BenedictFlorance -Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_ - Just use google "php htaccess tutorial"

Comment: @BenedictFlorance - https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ reference used

Comment: Sorry @MagnusEriksson, new to the forum, will follow the rule hereafter. Thanks Hothi Jimit.

Comment: @HothiJimit What do I need to do if I need to change every url of the form yourwebsite.com/snippet.php?id=1n69ak2 to yourwebsite.com/1n69ak2

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ snippet.php?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]   here automatic  snippet.php file name remove